# "Create Test Script in current folder" button is grayed out in Unity

Tags: unity

I thoroughly read [the Unity Test Runner documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/testing-editortestsrunner.html).

It is said in the documentation that the button may be disabled only if the creation of the script will lead to an error.

> This option is disabled if adding a test script would result in a compilation error.

But I do not understand this. How could a creation of the script possibly lead to an error?

I will be grateful for any help provided.

[image]

[image]

I found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SeNOAVYaq9HUjsKAC2ZvRwKLD2MCNyV4LwcsP3BXm0s/edit) a little bit more info, but it did not help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable **Create Test Script in current folder** button you should change **Project** presentation to **Two column layout**.

[image]

Then choose **Editor** folder.

And then open or click **Test Runner** tab - it works!

Answer (score 1):

That button is disabled to prevent you from creating a Test Script in an unsupported location.

According to the [Unity Test Runner documentation you linked](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/testing-editortestsrunner.html), tests need to be placed in a special folder such as an Editor folder. Valid locations:

- Project Editor folder
- Assembly Definition file that references test assemblies that are Editor-only
- Precompiled assemblies that are in the Project’s Editor folder

A test script outside these valid locations would result in a compilation error (in Unity 2018.1) because `UnityEngine.TestTools` and `NUnit.Framework` namespaces which are required for test scripts would not be recognized.

To fix this issue, use that Test Runner window when you're in an Editor folder (or another valid location). The button will be enabled once you open or click on the Test Runner window while your Project is at a valid location.

For PlayMode tests, for that button to be enabled, you also need to make sure that "Enable playmode tests runner" has been toggled on in the Test Runner context menu. (The context menu button is at the top-right corner of the Test Runner window, just under the "x" button to close.) Once this is enabled and you re-open the Editor as prompted, the Test Runner window should look like this with the button enabled:

[image: screenshot-fixed-and-context-menu]

(Also, see [Unity's documentation on Special folder names](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html) for more details about the Editor folder.)

Comment: I was in `Editor` folder when I tried this out. Did you manage to make the button enabled on your laptop?

Comment: I will update the question to show that the button is disabled even when I am in the `Editor` folder.

Comment: Yes it works for me. The button is enabled if I’m in the Editor folder. I had to click on the test runner window to get the button to refresh though.

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov are you trying to create EditMode tests or PlayMode tests? Do they both not work with that button?

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov for PlayMode tests, I've updated my answer to include that "Enable playmode tests runner" option should be toggled on in the Test Runner context menu (the menu is at the top-right of that window, under the "X")

Comment: I was able to make the button enabled for the play mode. But I still struggle with doing that for the editor mode.

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov I don’t have any more ideas on what the problem could be. Perhaps you can try in a blank Unity project, or create the script yourself from Unity documentation examples or other examples online. I don’t think you need to use the button if you can find an example of what the test script is supposed to look like. Unity 2017.3 has a different Ui for this so you could also try there and bring the scripts to your 2018.1 project.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the attention. If you happen to succeed in creating the editor test script, please tell me how you managed to do that.